# Block/Prevent Adminer - Apache

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, security

I found out that if someone was able to hack any FTP account on my server and upload Adminer they could alter the database. I tried Google'ing a way to block or prevent Adminer from working, but got no where. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying your server is already compromised, or you're just worrying about this one piece of malware?  If you're just worrying about Adminer, you should think more generally about securing your server, and that's too broad a question to answer here.

Answer (score 3):

> Anyone have any ideas?

Fix the problem, not the symptom. Stop using unencrypted FTP, it's highly insecure, and take other steps to secure your system. Blocking Adminer doesn't block any of the dozens of other similar systems (in PHP and otherwise), nor does it block someone from writing custom code that also alters the database.

If they get your FTP username and password, it's game over already. Use SFTP with key-based authentication for starters. The database should use separate a username/password so even if someone got a script onto your server it couldn't access the database without that also being compromised.

Comment: Amen. And i will only add, if the box got compromised, I would think to reinstall the OS to prevent any other possible rootkit.

Comment: There are some additional tips on securing a system linked from [the duplicate](http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server) which would be worth reading.